# Unable to install python turtle library with pip under Zorin OS

Tags: python, pip, turtle-graphics

I try to install turtle with pip but I am systematically confronted with the following error:

```
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [7 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "/tmp/pip-install-8wzjl5n4/turtle_55dccc7a15f942698d04888980888d3a/setup.py", line 40
          except ValueError, ve:
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      SyntaxError: multiple exception types must be parenthesized
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

I noticed that this error is not present when I try to install other libraries or when I try under other OS like Windows.

Comment: what version of python are you using

Comment: turtle is a part of base python. you most likely tried installing https://pypi.org/project/turtle/ a package not updated since 2009 not python3 compatible.

Answer (score 0):

Module turtle is already installed with python. You don't need to install it via pip.

Answer (score 0):

That's what I thought but when I execute I have this mistake.

```
File "/home/gabriel/Documents/N.S.I/St-Valentine's day/birthday.py", line 1, in <module>
        import turtle
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'turtle'
```

Little subtlety: when I execute it from the bash terminal it works fine but in vscode I always get errors when it comes to using libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe VSCode is a Flatpak(https://flatpak.org/) and doesnt gave acces to your systemwide pip, try deinstalling VsCode and download and install it from the offical Website with the deb(https://code.visualstudio.com/).